# Streaming the contents of a dynamic file through websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a program in Bash which runs a console feed. The feed is text, and is appended to each time an event happens and is timestamped.

How would I load the contents of the console feed onto a page (perhaps last 200 lines or so of the console), and send additional data each time the file was appended to (the new lines)?

I am completely new to WebSockets and the moving of dynamic data, so please explain anything thoroughly.

Note: I also have node.js installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have node.js, you should definitely check out [socket.io](http://socket.io/); it'll take care of all the WebSocket stuff for you. Check out the site to learn how to use it.

Also, since you're interested in watching a file for changes, check out the [`fs.watchFile()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) function of the FileSystem module of node.js. It'll fire a callback every time a file is changed. You can use this to get the new data and pipe it to the browser using `socket.emit()`.

Comment: If the file is ONLY being appended to, then you could just keep track of the file size and where you last read from in the file and only read the amount that changed from the your last position.